# How to use fonts in ConTeXt with \definefontfamiy?

Tags: fonts, context

I am following this page: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefontfamily

For some reason, the code

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [stixtwo]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [ss] [dejavu,ss]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [mm] [stixtwo]

\setupbodyfont[mainface]

\starttext

    Hello \bf world
    
    \ss
    Hello \bf world
    
    $hello world$

\stoptext
```

Produces a file with Latin Modern. It seems that the problem is:

```
selectfont      > the requested font 'stixtwo' has no files for the 'tf' alternative, Latin Modern is used instead.
selectfont      > the requested font 'dejavu,ss' has no files for the 'tf' alternative, Latin Modern is used instead.
selectfont      > the requested font 'stixtwo' has no files for the 'tf' alternative, Latin Modern is used instead.
fonts           > preloading modern-designsize (mono)
fonts           > 'fallback modern-designsize tt 12pt' is loaded
```

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE:** The suggested code by @mickep:

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [STIXTwoText]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [ss] [DejaVuSans] [rscale=0.85]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [mm] [STIXTwoMath]

\definefontfeature[default][default][goodies=stix-two-math.lfg]

\setupbodyfont[mainface]

\starttext

    Hello {\bf world}, {\it what} {\bi is up?}
    
    {\ss Hello {\bf world}, {\it what} {\bi is up?}}
    
    $\sin x = \int_0^x \cos t\dd t$

\stoptext
```

Doesn't work for Stix, and gives the following error:

```
selectfont      > the requested font 'STIXTwoText' has no files for the 'tf' alternative, Latin Modern is used instead.
selectfont      > the requested font 'STIXTwoMath' has no files for the 'tf' alternative, Latin
```

Modern is used instead.

**EDIT:**

The result of the `mtxrun --script fonts --list --all | grep stixtwotext` command

```
stixtwotext                                  stixtwotext                        stixtwotext                            /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/STIXTwoText.ttf                                       regular medium semibold bold
stixtwotextbold                              stixtwotext                        stixtwotextbold                        STIXTwoText-Bold.otf
stixtwotextbolditalic                        stixtwotext                        stixtwotextbolditalic                  STIXTwoText-BoldItalic.otf
stixtwotextitalic                            stixtwotext                        stixtwotextitalic                      STIXTwoText-Italic.otf
stixtwotextmedium                            stixtwotext                        stixtwotextmedium                      STIXTwoText-Medium.otf
stixtwotextmediumitalic                      stixtwotext                        stixtwotextmediumitalic                STIXTwoText-MediumItalic.otf
stixtwotextnormal                            stixtwotext                        stixtwotextitalic                      STIXTwoText-Italic.otf
stixtwotextregular                           stixtwotext                        stixtwotextregular                     STIXTwoText-Regular.otf
stixtwotextsemibold                          stixtwotext                        stixtwotextsemibold                    STIXTwoText-SemiBold.otf
stixtwotextsemibolditalic                    stixtwotext                        stixtwotextsemibolditalic              STIXTwoText-SemiBoldItalic.otf
```

Comment: Do you have the fonts? For example `<installation directory>/tex/texmf/fonts/data/stix/stix2/STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf`.

Comment: @mickep Yes, the fonts are installed.

Comment: Sorry, then I cannot help you. By the way, after the next upload, the `\definefontfeature` line should go away.

Comment: You can add the output from `mtxrun --script fonts --list --all stixtwo*` to your question to see which font files are found by ConTeXt.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster I have added the info to the question

Comment: Maybe the same for `stixtwomath`.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Can you disable the **STIX Two Text** (can be done with the macOS font manager) which comes with your system (it's listed as first entry in the font listing) and rebuild the ConTeXt font cache with `mtxrun --script fonts --reload --force`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster Unfortunately, these fonts cannot be disabled (`Fonts automatically installed by Apple are selected. These fonts cannot be deleted or deactivated.`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you use the names from the typescripts. I tried the following

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [STIXTwoText]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [ss] [DejaVuSans] [rscale=0.85]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [mm] [STIXTwoMath]

\setupbodyfont[mainface]

\starttext

    Hello {\bf world}, {\it what} {\bi is up?}
    
    {\ss Hello {\bf world}, {\it what} {\bi is up?}}
    
    $\sin x = \int_0^x \cos t\dd t$

\stoptext
```

and got this output:

[image: small example]

There might be better ways to force the stixtwo goodie file to be used (I think you want it, try without). Also, I looked in the stixtwo typescript file, and it seems that it has no sans serif font added (but dejavu for mono). I don't know if dejavu is a good match, but it is perhaps better than nothing. I can investigate a bit.

Comment: `DejaVu` works, but for some reason `Stix` still gets replaced with `Latin Modern`. Maybe there is a problem with my installation?

Comment: Strange. I use the latest update, but I do not think this has changed recently. Do you get any results if you do `mtxrun --script fonts --list --all | grep stixtwotext`.

Comment: yes, I get a lot of results. I have just installed the MXLT version for arm64 MacOS following the official webpage. If I replace all of the preamble with `\setupbodyfont[stixtwo]`, it works (but `\setupbodyfont[stixtwotext]` doesn't work).

Comment: There is no reason why `\setupbodyfont[stixtwotext]` should work. I suggest that you update your question with the example that I gave, and report the message(s) you get.

Comment: I have updated the question